# 404 Error in htaccess clean url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website but i am getting 404 error while using clean url for my post URL

.htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)/?$ post.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Files in Server is like :

```
index.php
post.php
.htaccess
```

all in one main public_html folder

this URL is working fine http://www.example.com/1

but i have 404 error in http://www.example.com/post/12345

i don't know what's problem... plz tell me what to do

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off multiviews by adding this somewhere in your htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
```